# How to solve NoSuchElementException in eclipse for getText

Tags: selenium

Write a script to print the getText present in the flipkart page ??

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[. = 'x']")).click();
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//h2[@class='_2cAig-'])[1]"));
        
        String str = ele.getText();
        System.out.println(str);
        
            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem is with `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[. = 'x']")).click();` This is really strange, new one on me. I tried that xpath on your page and I think I found out why it doesn't work. The character that is in that button tag *is actually not an ***x****, it's this character (I copied it from the page html): ✕ ; notice how this differ from x. and it actually seems to work if you just switch to the other character, like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[. = '✕']")).click();
```

If you have issues getting that special character to work we can probably find another selector for the button.